# Why saltstate returns ERROR with pkg.installed (Windows) while application installs?

Tags: windows, salt-stack

I'm Trying to install Antivirus softwate on salt minion (Windows 10) Cortex, usign salt-call.bat

Setup

```
{% set version = '73120981' %}
{% set source_path = 'INTERNAL_COMPANY_URL' %}

cortex:
  '{{version}}':
    {% if grains['cpuarch'] == 'AMD64' %}
    installer: '{{source_path}}/WindowsAgent{{version|replace(".", "_")}}_x64.msi'
    uninstaller: '{{source_path}}/WindowsAgent{{version|replace(".", "_")}}_x64.msi'
    arch: x64
    {% else %}
    installer: '{{source_path}}/WindowsAgent{{version|replace(".", "_")}}_x86.msi'
    uninstaller: '{{source_path}}/WindowsAgent{{version|replace(".", "_")}}_x86.msi'
    arch: x86
    {% endif %}
    full_name: 'Cortex {{version}}'
    install_flags: '/qn /norestart'
    uninstall_flags: '/qn /norestart'
    msiexec: True
    locale: en_US
    reboot: False
```

Below state calls with this state:

```
install_cortex:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: cortex
```

When I execute command salt-call state.sls, I'm gettings this error:

```
C:\salt>salt-call.bat state.sls cortex
[ERROR   ] {'cortex': {'install status': 'success'}, 'Cortex XDR 7.3.1.20981': {'old': '', 'new': '7.3.1.20981'}}
local:
----------
          ID: install_cortex
    Function: pkg.installed
        Name: cortex
      Result: False
     Comment: The following packages failed to install/update: cortex
     Started: 20:07:05.612151
    Duration: 109018.207 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              Cortex XDR 7.3.1.20981:
                  ----------
                  new:
                      7.3.1.20981
                  old:
              cortex:
                  ----------
                  install status:
                      success

Summary for local
------------
Succeeded: 0 (changed=1)
Failed:    1
------------
Total states run:     1
Total run time: 109.018 s
```

But if I run salt-call pkg.install everything goes ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a probable solution:

1. Install cortex manually
2. Go to control panel and capture the name and version from there.
3. In your repo file mention the exact captured name under full_name and exact captured version for version.
4. Do a genrepo and refresh_db.

This should resolve the issue.